# Как получать связанные данные через User manager?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp, asp.net-identity-2

У меня есть таблица Users унаследованная от IdentityUser. Есть связанная таблица Profile, связь один к одному.

Через UserManager я могу получить данные главной страницы, но данные связанной не могу. Мне нужно именно через менеджера делать,т.к данные отображаются на страницах.

Вот как я пробовал:

```
user.FirstName = "Введенное имя";
user.PhoneNumber = "Введенный номер";

user.Profile.Bio = "Введенная инфа";
user.Profile.Location = "Введенная инфа";

await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Данные не сохраняются и пишет что user.Profile = null. Если сделать через new, то в БД будет создаваться всё время новые записи а не редактироваться.

Также в представлении я получаю инфу с главной таблицы:
`@user.FirstName` с помощью inject UserManager.

Так вот, мне нужно заполнять и читать связанные данные с помощью UserManager. Потому что связанных таблиц будет много.